# Build simple hierarchy in YAML

Tags: yaml

I am trying to do what I thought would be simple in YAML. This is a simple hierarchy with repeating elements. The first example below is very close, but each *node* sequence element triggers the error: "bad indentation of a sequence entry".  I can't see what is wrong with it.

Note I include an example further down that works, but it uses unique keys which is not what I want.

```
- agegrp: 1 
  - node      : "(14, 6)"
    # id: "(14, 6)"
    - branch  : "to 7"
      id      : "to 7"
      tocond  : 7
      pr      : 1.0
      next    : (0, 0)
  - node      : "(14, 7)"
      # id: "(14,7)" 
    - branch  : "to 7" 
      id      : "to 7"
      tocond  : 7 
      pr      : 0.85 
      next    : (0, 0) 
    - branch  : "to 8" 
      id      : "to 8"
      tocond  : 8
      pr      :  0.15
      next    : (4, 4)
- agegrp      : 2 
  - node      : "(14, 6)"
    # id: "(14, 6)"
    - branch  : "to 7"
      id      : "to 7"
      tocond  : 7
      pr      : 1.0
      next    : (0, 0)
  - node      : "(14, 7)"
      # id: "(14,7)" 
    - branch  : "to 7" 
      id      : "to 7"
      tocond  : 7 
      pr      : 0.85 
      next    : (0, 0) 
    - branch  : "to 8" 
      id      : "to 8"
      tocond  : 8
      pr      :  0.15
      next    : (4, 4)
```

Note that the following works, but I don't want branch and node to have unique names. I want a repeating structure. I can use a dash in front of branch and node, but this causes a different problem: bad indentation of a sequence entry.

```
agegrp:
id: 1
node (14, 6): 
  # id: "(14, 6)"
  branch: 
    id: "to 7"
    tocond: 7
    pr: 1.0
    next: (0, 0)
node (14,7): 
  # id: "(14,7)" 
  branch to 7: 
    id: "to 7"
    tocond: 7 
    pr: 0.85 
    next: (0, 0) 
  branch to 8: 
    id: "to 8"
    tocond: 8
    pr:  0.15
    next: (4, 4)
```

There will be 5 age groups. Nodes are within agegroups. Branches are within nodes. Each branch has 3 properties. I am ok with an id item under each node, rather than as I show above.

I am confused about when I must use a leading dash and when not. I am confused about when a value is allowed and when not.

Is this even possible in YAML? TOML doesn't like hierarchies. Up to this point I have it in csv and parse that and build a dictionary in code. I thought I could use a format that would natively represent the hierarchy.

The output I would like:

- either an array or dictionary of ages. There will never be more than 10 and an array would be fine.
- for each age group a dict of nodes
- for each node either an array or dict of branches

Here is an example:  here is one dict for an age group:

```
(1, 1) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(5, 5, 0.2, (2, 1), "nil", "nil")
   CovidSim.Branch(5, 6, 0.65, (2, 2), "nil", "mild")
   CovidSim.Branch(5, 7, 0.15, (2, 3), "nil", "sick")
(2, 1) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(5, 3, 0.8, (0, 0), "nil", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(5, 7, 0.2, (3, 3), "nil", "sick")
(2, 2) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(6, 6, 1.0, (3, 2), "mild", "mild")
(2, 3) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 7, 0.85, (3, 3), "sick", "sick")
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 8, 0.15, (3, 4), "sick", "severe")
(3, 2) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(6, 3, 1.0, (0, 0), "mild", "recovered")
(3, 3) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 3, 0.8, (0, 0), "sick", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 7, 0.1, (5, 3), "sick", "sick")
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 8, 0.1, (4, 4), "sick", "severe")
(3, 4) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 3, 0.45, (0, 0), "severe", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 8, 0.5, (4, 4), "severe", "severe")
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 4, 0.05, (0, 5), "severe", "dead")
(4, 4) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 3, 0.85, (0, 0), "severe", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 8, 0.1, (5, 4), "severe", "severe")
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 4, 0.05, (0, 5), "severe", "dead")
(5, 3) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 3, 0.9, (0, 0), "sick", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(7, 4, 0.1, (0, 5), "sick", "dead")
(5, 4) =>
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 3, 0.6, (0, 0), "severe", "recovered")
   CovidSim.Branch(8, 4, 0.4, (0, 5), "severe", "dead")
```

The outer container is an array of 5 agegroup dicts.

(Note, this example contains some extra fields in each branch that I am reducing.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I was not getting my head around YAML and creating entity groups without any name. @KeepCalmAndCarryOn: Your structure resulted in an array of nodes with an id item and a branches item at the same level (the branches item is an array of the branches, each branch being a dict of the properties. This works but doesn't display very nicely and is harder to work with (but certainly contains all the information from my example).

I prefer a strict hierarchy. I hand-coded json. Then, parsed the json to a nested julia object:  an array of dicts like this:

```
Dict{String,Any} with 5 entries:
  "4" => Dict{String,Any}("(9,6)"=>Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any…
  "1" => Dict{String,Any}("(9,6)"=>Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any…
  "5" => Dict{String,Any}("(9,6)"=>Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any…
  "2" => Dict{String,Any}("(9,6)"=>Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any…
  "3" => Dict{String,Any}("(9,6)"=>Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any…
```

The output is truncated but you can see each agegroup as a key--with a dict of nodes as its value. Each dict of nodes shows the first key (a node) with an array of branches as its value. Each item in the branches array is a dict of the fields for each property of a branch.

One agegrp looks like this:

```
Dict{String,Any} with 8 entries:
  "(9,6)"  => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>6,"next"=>Any[14, 6],"pr"=>1.0)]
  "(9,5)"  => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>3,"next"=>Any[0, 0],"pr"=>0.8), Di…
  "(14,6)" => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>3,"next"=>Any[0, 0],"pr"=>1.0)]
  "(9,7)"  => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>7,"next"=>Any[14, 7],"pr"=>0.85), …
  "(5,5)"  => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>5,"next"=>Any[9, 5],"pr"=>0.2), Di…
  "(14,8)" => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>3,"next"=>Any[0, 0],"pr"=>0.45), D…
  "(14,7)" => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>3,"next"=>Any[0, 0],"pr"=>0.85), D…
  "(19,8)" => Any[Dict{String,Any}("tocond"=>3,"next"=>Any[0, 0],"pr"=>0.9), Di…
```

Then, I took this Julia nested object (a bit gnarly, but with clearer structure--at least to me) and put it through YAML to create valid YAML output.

This YAML is just what I really wanted, even if it seems nasty-ish to someone who uses YAML properly. Here is just one agegrp (the others are identical in structure and follow sequentially in the YAML document):

```
4:                     # the id of an agegrp
  (9,6):               # the id of a node
    - tocond: 6        # first property of a branch
      next:
        - 14
        - 6
      pr: 1.0
  (9,5):
    - tocond: 3
      next:
        - 0
        - 0
      pr: 0.8
    - tocond: 7
      next:
        - 14
        - 7
      pr: 0.2
  (14,6):
    - tocond: 3
      next:
        - 0
        - 0
      pr: 1.0
  (9,7):
    - tocond: 7
      next:
        - 14
        - 7
      pr: 0.85
    - tocond: 8
      next:
        - 14
        - 8
      pr: 0.15
  <rest of output truncated...>
```

This follows the hierarchy I wanted:

```
top: an agegroup id
  then a node (with more following after the indented children)
     then a branch
       then an array of the branches properties
```

I really messed myself up by mixing the name of the entities (agegrp, node, branch) with actual values of specific instances of each entity--like I was trying to label each thing with its type. You wouldn't do that in a Dict. I am using Julia here, but Dicts are essentially the same as in Python.

So, a bit of a frustrating foray into YAML. But, it will a lot easier to enter than the CSV I started with and much easier than hand authoring JSON. So, a successful foray!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963) for collections

> YAML’s block collections use indentation for scope and begin each
> entry on its own line.
>
> Block sequences indicate each entry with a dash
> and space ( “- ”).
>
> Mappings use a colon and space (“: ”) to mark each
> key: value pair.
>
> Comments begin with an octothorpe (also called a
> “hash”, “sharp”, “pound”, or “number sign” - “#”).

so your

```
- agegrp: 1
```

is a fusion  of a sequence and a map

you could do something like this

```
--- 
- 
  id: 1
  nodes: 
    - 
      branches: 
        - 
          id: "to 7"
          next: "(0, 0)"
          pr: 1.0
          tocond: 7
        - 
          id: "to 7"
          next: "(0, 0)"
          pr: 0.85
          tocond: 7
        - 
          id: "to 8"
          next: "(4, 4)"
          pr: 0.15
          tocond: 8
      id: "(14, 6)"
```

If that suits your needs

Comment: I do need multiple ages, but I could use the same approach as you propose for nodes. Do I need the --- for front matter?  Would the next id for 2nd age group go in the group introduced with the bare -? Or after a new bare group marker? For a format meant to be "easy" and human readable, YAML certainly is peculiar.  Yes, your approach can meet my needs, so thanks. I'll try it out and then mark it as answer if works (and I don't screw up).

Comment: you can get away without the `---` at the front. I put it through an online formatter. That is used to separate top level entities. Yes a `-` followed by a second section as that is a sequence, or array. It is easy compared to JSON or XML. You really have to watch the spaces when creating it by hand or use an editor, online or otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Following up on your own answer: YAML *does* allow you to put the names of the entities into a YAML file. It does so by providing syntax for *tags*. Here's an example how your file could look like:

```yaml
!agegrp 4:
  !node [9,6]:
    - !branch
      tocond: 6
      next:
        - 14
        - 6
      pr: 1.0
  !node [9,5]:
    - !branch
      tocond: 3
      next:
        - 0
        - 0
      pr: 0.8
    - !branch
      tocond: 7
      next:
        - 14
        - 7
      pr: 0.2
```

Note that I use YAML sequences for the node coordinates, since it looks like you want to parse them into numeric pairs anyway (`(9,6)` would be parsed as string). You could keep the original syntax instead.

What this does is to associate the value directly after the tag with it. So `4` will be tagged `!agegrp`, the sequence `[9,6]` will be tagged `!node`, and the mapping containing `tocond` etc will be tagged `!branch`. Local tags like these are application-defined; you will need to register handlers for them with most YAML implementations.

Semantically, this would mark `4` as *agegrp* (whatever that is), while the nodes are not part of that *agegrp* object – with this markup, only the key `4` is tagged as *agegrp*. How you process the file is up to you, of course. An alternative would be:

```yaml
4: !agegrp
  !node [9,6]:
    …
```

Now, the mapping containing the nodes is marked *agegrp* and the `4` is just a key in a mapping (probably parsed as integer).

If you want the IDs to be part of the objects, you could shift the document to a sequence-based structure, **@KeepCalmAndCarryOn** already showed the usual way to do this, here is one using tags:

```yaml
- !agegrp
  - !id 4
  - !node
    - !id [9,6]
    - !branch
      tocond: 6
      next:
        - 14
        - 6
      pr: 1.0
  - !node
    - !id [9,5]
    - !branch
      tocond: 3
      next:
        - 0
        - 0
      pr: 0.8
    - !branch
      tocond: 7
      next:
        - 14
        - 7
      pr: 0.2
```

What this does is to flatten the internal structure of *node* so that the ID and the branches can be on the same level. This requires the loading code to properly distinguish between `!id` and `!branch` nodes when loading that YAML. This kind of structure is often used in XML which does not provide mappings like YAML does and therefore, all nested structures are sequences and different children are distinguished by their element names.

Comment: That's a great suggestion!. Unfortunately, the YAML parser for Julia hasn't implemented tags yet so I can't add the tag handlers. Since I can't use the tags I can use comments so it is easy for a user to edit the tree input file.  AND--I did switch to using 2 element arrays for the node names used for node and the property next. Julia does allow arrays as dict keys (no Python restriction to immutables for keys). So, now I can skip any post processing. The trees load as needed by the application with nothing to do. And they are easy to edit. This all turned out really well.